# Php. AOL Search Trends

Tags: php

Почему-то нет вывода :(. Что я делаю не так?

```
<?php
    $trendurl = 'http://search.aol.com/aol/trends';
    $gtrend = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_URL,$trendurl);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $trend = curl_exec($gtrend);
    preg_match_all("/<li><a href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a><\/li>/is", $trend, $keywords, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    $i=0;
    while ($i<50)
    {

    ?>
    <li><a href="http://blabla.cnet/?key=<?php echo strtolower($r); ?>"><?php echo $keywords[1][$i]; ?></a></li>
    <?php
        $i++;
    }
    curl_close($gtrend);
    ?>
```

Пожалуйста помогите доработать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько замечаний по коду:

1. Сервер не отдает с таким юзерагентом контент. Можете проверить, выполнив `echo $trend` после curl_exec()
2. В регулярном выражении вы не учитываете переносы строк между li и a, /a и /li
3. Что такое $r?

С учетом этих изменений и немного отрефакторив код у меня получилось так (что такое $r я не знаю, поэтому оставил его как есть):

```
<?php
    $trendurl = 'http://search.aol.com/aol/trends';
    $gtrend = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_URL, $trendurl);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $trend = curl_exec($gtrend);
    curl_close($gtrend);

    $pattern = '/<li>[\r\n]*<a[\s\t]+href=[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>[\r\n]*<\/li>/i';
?>
<?php if (preg_match_all($pattern, $trend, $keywords)) : ?>
    <p>Hourly</p>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach(array_slice($keywords[1], 0, 50) as $linkText) : ?>
            <li><a href="http://blabla.cnet/?key=<?= strtolower($r) ?>"><?= $linkText ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <p>Daily</p>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach(array_slice($keywords[1], 50) as $linkText) : ?>
            <li><a href="http://blabla.cnet/?key=<?= strtolower($r) ?>"><?= $linkText ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно сделать как на aol в две колонки?
Hourly - Daily

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать вместо регулярного выражения специальные инструменты для работы с деревом HTML (SimpleXML, PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser и т.п.). Но если нужно вот так сразу, то получается первые 50 - это hourly, последующие - daily. Т.е. как вариант:

    $hourly = array_slice($keywords[1], 0, 50);
    $daily = array_slice($keywords[1], 50);

Comment: Что-то я туплю... В php Не очень силен... Можно рабочий пример в php где есть hourly и daily

Comment: @jikol, обновил код в ответе

Comment: Загляните в документацию по [array_slice][1]

У нее в параметрах задаются (массив, от, сколько). Если вам нужно 20 для hourly и 10 для daily, то соответственно поправьте строки на

    array_slice($keywords[1], 0, 20)
    <...>
    array_slice($keywords[1], 50, 10)

и получите нужные данные

   [1]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Спасибо, только-что понял и у вас ответ уже )

Comment: @jikol, если ответ исчерпывающий, пометьте его галочкой ниже кнопок-лайков